# Printing array values by a repeating pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [a, b, c];
```

In above array,
index 0 contains "a",
index 1 contains "b",
index 2 contains "c".

```
console.log(arr[0])  // will print > "a"
console.log(arr[1])  // will print > "b"
console.log(arr[2])  // will print > "b"
```

Is there a way so that if I want to `console.log(arr[3])` then it should print `"a"` again, `console.log(arr[4])` would be `"b"` and so on. If we want an index of let's say 42 like this `console.log(arr[42])` then it should print any of those three string values by following the same pattern.

Answer (score 3):

simply use with `%` like this `arr[value % arr.length]`.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function finding(val){
return arr[val % arr.length];
}
console.log(finding(0))
console.log(finding(1))
console.log(finding(2))
console.log(finding(3))
console.log(finding(4))
console.log(finding(5))
console.log(finding(6))
console.log(finding(42))
```

Comment: Straightforward and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

We can define our custom function which give the appropriate index

```js
function getIndex(num){
  return num%3;/* modulo operator*/ 
}
var arr=["a","b","c"];
console.log(arr[getIndex(0)]);
console.log(arr[getIndex(1)]);
console.log(arr[getIndex(2)]);
console.log(arr[getIndex(3)]);
console.log(arr[getIndex(4)]);
console.log(arr[getIndex(5)]);
console.log(arr[getIndex(41)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot have exactly what you are looking for. But what we can have what you are looking for by this

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
var printToThisIteration = function(n){
    var length = arr.length;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
     {
         console.log(arr[i%length])

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using  `%` you can have it repeat as many times as you like.

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'];

let repetitions = 5;

for(var i = 0; i < repetitions; i++){
  console.log(arr[i%3]);
}
```